# Creating meme command with discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Can someone help me how to create meme command like dank memer. Below is the photo of the command i want to make.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6BUQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the meme command I am using now. This is also similar to dank memer.
This is from the library of discord_compoenents. You can refer the docs for using the button

```py
    @commands.command(aliases=['me'])
    @commands.guild_only()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 3, commands.BucketType.user)    
    async def meme(self,ctx):
      serverId = ctx.message.guild.id    
      def meme_opt():
            choices=[1,2]
            chosen=random.choice(choices)
            if(chosen==1):
              '''Post a meme'''
              r = requests.get("https://memes.blademaker.tv/api?lang=en")
              res = r.json()
              title = res["title"]
              ups = res["ups"]
              # downs = res["downs"]
              comments = res['score']
              authors=res["author"]
              memes = discord.Embed(title=f"{title}",colour=randint(0, 0xffffff))
              memes.set_image(url=res["image"])
              memes.set_footer(text=f" : {ups}  ✍️ : {authors}    : {comments} ")
            else:
              ###################
              r=requests.get("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme")
              res=r.json()
              title=res["title"]
              ups=res["ups"]
              author=res["author"]
              link=res["postLink"]
              memes = discord.Embed(description=f"[{title}]({link})",colour=randint(0, 0xffffff))
              memes.set_image(url=res["url"])
              memes.set_footer(text=f" : {ups} ✍️ : {author}")
            return memes

      components = [
          [
              Button(label='Next meme', style=ButtonStyle.green, custom_id='next'),
              Button(label='End interaction', style=ButtonStyle.red, custom_id='exit')
          ]
      ]

      message = await ctx.send(embed=meme_opt(), components=components)
      id=message.id
      while True:
          try:
              interaction = await self.bot.wait_for(
                  'button_click',
                  check=lambda inter: inter.message.id == message.id,
                  timeout=30
              )
          except asyncio.TimeoutError:
              for row in components:
                  row.disable_components()
              return await message.edit(components=components)

          if(interaction.author.id==ctx.author.id):
                if(interaction.custom_id=="next"):
                  await interaction.edit_origin(embed=meme_opt(),components=components)
                elif(interaction.custom_id=="exit"):
                  for row in components:
                    row.disable_components()
                  message=await ctx.fetch_message(id)   
                  return await interaction.edit_origin(embed=message.embeds[0],components=components)
          else:
            await interaction.send("Hey! This is not for you!")
```

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if it worked for you

Comment: "https://memes.blademaker.tv/api?lang=en" this link ain't working anymore...